# Error Creating Endpoint Attachment between Private Service Connect and Integration Connectors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sftp, ip-address, static-ip-address

I am trying to establish a connection between an SFTP server and our Google Cloud project to eventually ingest some data into BigQuery from the SFTP server. I am using Integration Connectors on GCP to create this connection to the SFTP server. The server provider will need to whitelist our Google Cloud servers' region IPs to allow for this connection to establish. The SFTP server provider is asking for what IP addresses to whitelist.

I have created a Private Service Connect endpoint with a static IP, and I am now attempting to create an Endpoint Attachment from Integration Connectors to this PSC endpoint. When I do this, I am faced with an error that says nothing else than:

"Creating endpoint attachment sftp-endpoint-attachment in europe-north1

Unknown error."

I would appreciate some help in resolving what this error might depend on and how to correctly establish this connection.

Kind regards,
Bertan

Comment: Can you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-ip-address#:~:text=You%20view%20the%20internal%20and,or%20the%20Compute%20Engine%20API.&text=In%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20console,under%20the%20External%20IP%20column.) if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[SFTP Connector](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/connectors/sftp/configure) you can use this link as a guide to connect to an SFTP server. From the documentation it will show the requirements you need in order to connect to an SFTP server.

Regarding IP addresses on a specific region, this can be done once a server is deployed and it will show you the information of an IP address that you need to whitelist. This can be shown in the [Viewing IP Addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-ip-address#:%7E:text=You%20view%20the%20internal%20and,or%20the%20Compute%20Engine%20API.&text=In%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20console,under%20the%20External%20IP%20column.) documentation.